# call a native program from servlet

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, servlets

I need to call a native program thta will run on the server where a JSF servlet is executing. I think I have to deal with the Process object, is this right or is it a better way? Moreover, which changes do I have to do on the policy file so that only such web application/servlet running on tomcat can call the native program?

Comment: What O/S are you running?  That will make a difference on how you set permissions to the executable. You use the [Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) method to execute a program outside of Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("<name of executable>");
```

Haven't tested it, but it should be close.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Tomcat, you may be able to take advantage of the CGI sevrlet to do this for you. If not, I at least suggest you take a look at the [CGI Servlet code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/servlets/CGIServlet.java?view=annotate) starting around line 1600 to get an idea of the things you need to take into consideration regarding input/output stream handling etc.